# Why is it so hard to center divs in HTML?

Tags: html, css, center

Why does this code not center all three elements inside the outer div?

```css
.center 
{
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 70%;
}
```

```html
<div class="center">
  <h1 class="center">Headline</h1>

  <div class="center"><span>Some text</span></div>

  <form class="center">
    <button>Button</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

How can I do this, without specifying absolute values?
Why is it so hard to center divs in HTML with hacks like `margin-left: auto;` and `margin-right: auto;`?

Comment: Centering in html is horrible... they urgently need to improve this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add `text-align: center`

here's an example 
https://jsfiddle.net/txtz8duL/

```
.center {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 70%;
  text-align: center;  
}
```

and some more variations here: 
https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/

Comment: Nice, but the fact is in many cases it simply doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

To center align the text or inline elements, you just need to use `text-align: center;`

Auto margin is set to align for some fixed width element with inline-block or block level element.

So, in your case the following centers the div element but not text:

```
.center {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 70%;
}
```

Adding text-align: center will align the text too:

```
.center {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 70%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```css
  .center {
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 width: 70%;
 text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="center">
  <!-- container -->
  <h1 class="center">Headline</h1>

  <div class="center">Some text</div>

  <form class="center">
    <button>Button</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/1sx6fuxw/) is an example, is this what you are looking for?

[Here](https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/) is a good guide for centering elements

I think you should separate the elements and not try to use a one-size fits all class, specially when you want to refer to divs and texts, it might get dirtier as you scale the project. But, the above example uses your code since it seems you want to use the same class for all the items. I used `display: block` in case the element isn't a block item.

The above centers the items.

Keep in mind that

CSS

```
.center {
  display: block;
  width: 70%;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use text-align to center any things like this:
`<h1 style="text-align:center"> Sample Heading</h1>`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can use `<center>` element to align its content to center.

Unfortunately CSS has no means so far to reproduce `<center>` layout manager in full.

```html
<center>
  <!-- container -->
  <h1 class="center">Headline</h1>

  <div class="center">Some text</div>

  <form class="center">
    <button>Button</button>
  </form>
</center>
```

Update: technically `<center>` is deprecated in HTML5 but it works in all browsers. And will work until CSS will not have matching feature.

But you probably will be satisfied by this:

```css
.center {
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="center">
  <!-- container -->
  <h1 class="center">Headline</h1>

  <div class="center">Some text</div>

  <form class="center">
    <button>Button</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

When using margins with the properties of auto you need to feed a fixed value(Not a percentage) as the width.

For example your code would work if you changed the percent to a px, cm, in, or em value.

```
        .center
        {
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
            width: 70px;
        }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/s1napggb/

However in order to center elements with a floating value requires flexbox, CSS media queries or some Javascript.